# How to wrap each line in selected block with a character using Snippet in Sublimetext2?

Tags: sublimetext2

So, what I've got so far is the snippet that will wrap my selected text with an asterix:

```
<snippet>
   <content>
       <![CDATA[*$SELECTION*]]>
   </content>
</snippet>`
```

Which will do this if I've selected the first line and then envoked my snippet:

```
*feature-121203-poulan-pro-en.jpg*
feature-121203-poulan-pro-fr.jpg
outdoor-hero-121203-heattrak-en.jpg
outdoor-hero-121203-heattrak-fr.jpg
```

But how can I adjust my snippet so that if I select a block of lines, it will wrap each line independently, and not just wrap the entire block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your snippet as is: after selection, you can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>), to split the selection into lines. Then apply your snippet.

Comment: That was perfect. I'd never found a use for that split selection into lines feature before and now I will use it a lot. Thank you for your help.